# content: "\f068" seen as "?"

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver, pseudo-element

I want to trieve the value of content in my pseude element.

```
script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('small.fa.text-muted.fa-minus'),':before').getPropertyValue('content');";
js = (JavascriptExecutor) webdriver;
content = js.executeScript(script);
System.out.println("content : " + content);
```

Css

```
.fa-minus:before {
    content: "\f068";
}
```

For some reason my code doesn't return "\f068" but returns "?" instead. Why is that and what do I need to do to return "\f068"?

Debuging:

[image]

Comment: I'd guess this is because your console can't print that codepoint. Try `System.out.println("\uf068")`, see what that prints.

Comment: The backslash means that the content will be the actual character whose code is U+f068. You are going to get a single char there. Whether you can print it or not depends on the encoding of your console. It is rather unlikely because this character is in the unicode private use range, so it is not included in any standard font. You can check it with a debugger to verify that you got the correct character.

Comment: @ Andy, System.out.println("\uf068") prints a "?"

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Debug screenshot added in original post.

Comment: The debug shows another string - three characters: double quote, middle dot, double quote. Are you sure you got the value of the correct element?

Comment: I am pretty sure. If I hover with my mouse over "content" then I get the "?" inside the `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's how you could do it with javascript

```
var el = document.querySelector('.fa-minus'),
pseudoEl = window.getComputedStyle(el,'::after'),
content = pseudoEl.getPropertyValue("content"),
characterValue = '\\' + content.charCodeAt(1).toString(16);

console.log(characterValue);
```

I honestly don't know how much java and javascript are different from each other, so this is just my two cents :D

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/qjaysweh/2/)

Comment: You are a star!

Comment: @RicoStrydom glad i could help!

Comment: `String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('small.fa.text-muted.fa-minus'),':before').getPropertyValue('content').charCodeAt(1).toString(16);";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webdriver;
String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
System.out.println(content);`